# RC quality factor increase

Tags: rf, radio, tuning

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKadAw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit has a bandwidth of 0.9Hz but I want even lower bandwidth.

I have this RC tuning circuit. If i had an RLC tuning circuit I could play with the resistance to increase the quality factor-> increasing the selectivity.

Can I do something similar to this circuit?

Comment: What makes you think it has 0.9Hz bandwidth?

Comment: the cutoff lower frequency ( or -3Db Gain) is found  by 1/2piR1C1 and the cutoff higher frequency is found by 1/2piR2C2 .

Comment: Simulate it. Cascading 1st order filters doesn't work that way. (Plus, R2 will attenuate the signal getting to the speaker). Edit teh question and tell us what you're really trying to do here and what you have accomplished so far.

Comment: You typically need to move to an active filter to get a high Q